# How can I implement generic method which has generic return type and generic parameter?

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic interface `Service`:

```
public interface Service {
    public <T> T callService(T request);
}
```

I want to modify the `callService` method such that it can accept a generic parameter and return an instance of a *different* generic return type.  How do I do that, either with the above declaration or by modifying it?

Comment: You already did that, what's your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A generic is defined in the same way you have that example there, just have a placeholder for the type name. If you are looking to define it to have a generic input parameter type and a **different** generic return type then you can comma separate them.

```
public <T, R> R callService(T request);
```